# How to setup a Google Managed VMs Custom Runtime with App Engine service APIs

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, docker, google-app-engine-python

The default [google-managed-vms](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/) python runtime is `google/appengine-python27` a docker image based on `google/debian:wheezy`

How to setup a custom python runtime that would extend `debian:testing` and would support:

- Datastore
- Memcache
- Task Queues
- Logging

as `google/appengine-python27` does ?

Answer (score 0):

Read [there](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes)!

You can start to create a Dockerfile that extend the google/appengine-python27, to do that your Dockerfile need to start as shown below

```
# The image is based on the Debian Wheezy distribution.
FROM google/appengine-python
```

As described here

[image]

Comment: Yes, I do know how to extend the default python runtime. What I need is a runtime that extends `debian:testing`. I believe this cannot be achieved by extending the the default python runtime, isn't it ?

Comment: if you extend the python runtime it's ok because probably the google/appengine-python27 extend also the debian:testing :)

Comment: I don't understand as I'm a docker noob. Is that possible to extend both debian:testing and debian:stable? If so, what do I have to do to be sure that the image I use extends debian:testing ?

Comment: You should extend google/appengine-python, not more! :) I've attached an image to the answer to clarify